# Is there a way to prevent public variables from reverting to a previous value?

Tags: vba

I am using a search and change method using a combo box and buttons, but two important public variables continue to change to zero for no apparent reason.

The aim of the methods is to search for a device type, then search for a specific device and change the value of related cells. It seems to work after the first press of the button, but if the combo box is not changed and a button is pressed, the important variables, `OSSstockNum` and `OSSstartingRowNum`, are changed to zero, so the while loop isn't running.

```vb
public OSSstockNum As Integer
public OSSstartingRowNum As Integer

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    j = 1
    OSSfound = False

    While j <= Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row And OSSfound = False
        If Range("B" + CStr(j)).Value = ComboBox1.Value Then
            OSSfound = True
        Else
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Wend
    OSSstockNum = Range("I" + CStr(j)).Value
    OSSstartingRowNum = j + 2    
End Sub

Private Sub btnFaulty_Click()
    Dim intRowNum As Integer
    Dim OSSInput As String
    Dim CNAddress As String
    Dim statusAddress As String
    Dim assignAddress As String
    Dim condAddress As String

    OSSInput = InputBox("What is the Code of the " + ComboBox1.Value + " you 
    want to change to faulty?")
    intRowNum = 0
    OSSfound = False
    assignAddress = G1
    statusAddress = H1
    condAddress = I1

    While (intRowNum < OSSstockNum And OSSfound = False)
        CNAddress = "D" + CStr(OSSstartingRowNum + intRowNum)

        If Range(CNAddress).Value = OSSInput Then
            OSSfound = True
            assignAddress = "G" + CStr(OSSstartingRowNum + intRowNum)
            statusAddress = "H" + CStr(OSSstartingRowNum + intRowNum)
            condAddress = "I" + CStr(OSSstartingRowNum + intRowNum)
        Else
            intRowNum = intRowNum + 1
        End If
    Wend

    If OSSfound = True Then
        If (Range(statusAddress).Value = "FAULTY") Then
            MsgBox ("This device is already faulty")
        Else
            Range(assignAddress).Value = "FAULTY"
            Range(assignAddress).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206)
            Range(assignAddress).Font.Color = RGB(156, 0, 6)
            Range(statusAddress).Value = "FAULTY"
            Range(statusAddress).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206)
            Range(statusAddress).Font.Color = RGB(156, 0, 6)
            Range(condAddress).Value = "FAULTY"
            Range(condAddress).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206)
            Range(condAddress).Font.Color = RGB(156, 0, 6)
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox ("Sorry, the device you're looking for couldn't be found")
    End If
End Sub
```

If the input search term is found, it should change the value and formatting of the selected cells, but when the button is pressed a second time, the `while` loop in the button is being skipped, so true is still false, so it is saying that the device can't be found.

Comment: How do you know the while loop is skipped because "true is still false"? Did you set a breakpoint at `while` and examine the variables in the condition?

Comment: Sorry, what I'm saying is that the while loop is skipped (because the a break has found that OSSstocknum is zero), so the OSSfound value, which is only changed within the while loop, can't be changed to true. Therefore, the following if statement recognises that OSSfound is still false, so it's saying that it's not found, even if the searched value is there.